# Upgrading vs2012 project to vs2013 still displays project as vs2012

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I have a Visual Studio 2012 C++ project that I have upgraded to 2013, by opening the solution in vs2013 and choosing to upgrade.

However in the IDE, in Solution Explorer, when I am in Debug configuration the project displays as being a 2012 project. In release mode it correctly doesn't display the visual studio version ( which indicates it is 2013 ). I have checked the Platform Toolset setting for Debug configuration and it says 'Visual Studio 2013 (v120)'.

Are there any other settings that need to be set for the project to be considered 2013 ?

Answer (score 0):

Does the project have any .props or other (vcxproj) project files it may be referencing? If so, that might be cause of the error.